# Context behind physical equations and formulas

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conventions, mathematics

In a lot of cases we can sum up our problems with a well defined context such as which variables are 'changing' and which 'constant', in physical formulas we are given none of this so how can we make assumptions to which extent a given equation holds in my context depending on which variables are 'changing' or which other relationships may be constraining our values in the background?

What is the default 'context' that physical formulas are given as? Is it better to see them simply as a statement of things that may be true in different contexts, but even still how do we know the validity of the equations, for example if $F=ma$ this equation only holds if $m$ is constant.

Comment: I like the response from Steeven, but I want to emphasize that every equation has content and story behind it. $F=ma$ means absolutely nothing unless you tell me what each symbol means ($F$, $m$, and $a$), including any assumptions you are making (maybe "assuming $m$" is constant, but you also dropped the vector signs so maybe "...for a component of the net force" or something here too). There are also a whole series of complicated experimental "truths" that tell is when equations are "valid". There is always a relatively complicated context in physical equations.

Answer (score 1):

There are three fundamental approaches to a physical relationship/formula:

- Defined/axiomatic expressions such as $K=\frac 12 mv^2$. These are always true by definition. Whether they are useful depends on whether the definition is made to match a physical usecase.
- Derived relationships such as the kinematic motion equations e.g. $s=s_0+v_0t+\frac12at^2$. These are derived and proven from other relationships or definitions and are thus true only if those underlying ones are true.
- Emperical relationships such as Newton's laws, e.g. $\sum F=ma$, as well as basically all of our conservation laws. These are typically formulated over long time periods of trial and error. We can't be perfectly sure that they are true because they can't be proven rigidly. Rather, we test and test and test, typically aiming for *proof by contradiction*, and if we never find a contradiction, then be start believing that they might be true.

Gravity might be the most famous example of an emperical truth. We can't know for sure that a dropped pen will fall down - that it also fall down when dropped tomorrow - but we believe it to be true since we have never ever experienced a counter example.

As per the comment and also to answer the final bit of your question, all relationships may only be valid within certain domains if validity. Meaning, after all this testing that makes us trust these relationships as universally true, then we suddenly stumble upon a domain within which it *does* not hold true. Something we hadn't tested for because we weren't aware. When the relativity theories were developed, when quantum mechanics and dynamics underwent more studies etc. we found limiting cases and extremities were our trusted relationships and laws didn't hold true anymore.

So it is not a simple task to establish an emperical finding as truth universally. In fact it might be impossible.

Comment: F=ma is certainly not true. Neither is Newton's law of gravity. Even empirically these statements are limited to their fairly limited application domains. If dark energy exists and  we are living in an accelerating universe, then gravity may not even hold us on the floor forever. One day things would, indeed, start floating away...

Comment: @FlatterMann Good points. I have expanded a bit in the answer.

Comment: Over time I have come to accept your last point... we may never know the entire story. That's humbling, isn't it?